# XML varaiable substitution option will be only replaces the value for single key in web.config

Tags: xml, iis, web-config, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on DevOps with VSTS. I have one web project (for example webproject1) with Web.config file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

<configSections> 

<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" /> </configSections> 

<appSettings>

<add key="IndexDirectory" value="D:\wwwroot\XXXX\Indexes" /> 

</appSettings> 

<caching localActiveProvider="MemoryCacheProvider" globalActiveProvider="RedisCacheProvider"> <strategy name="LocalAndGlobal" localDefaultTTL="0:00:04:00" globalDefaultTTL="0:04:00:00" /> <provider name="RedisCacheProvider"> 

<setting name="connectionString" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

</provider>

<provider name="AppFabricCacheProvider"> 

<setting name="cacheName" value="XXXX"/>

<setting name="hostName" value="XXXX" /> 

<setting name="cachePort" value="22233" />

<setting name="maxConnectionsToServer" value="100" />

</provider> 

<provider name="MemoryCacheProvider"> 

</provider> <cacheKeyTTL> 

<add key="LoggedInEnabledUserIDs" value="0.00:02:00" /> 

</cacheKeyTTL> 

</caching> 

</configuration>
```

I created the release definition for web project in VSTS using IIS Web App Manage and IIS Web App Deploy Deployment tasks. I want to replaces the key values with client key values in Web.config file, for that I followed this documentation transform Web.Config file 'Properly' with VSTS and enabled the XML variable substitution option under File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options of IIS web App Deploy VSTS release task.

I declared the IndexDirectory, connectionString and maxConnectionsToServer with client vales under Variables tab. After release succeeded I observerd  that only the  IndexDirectory value is updating but connectionString and maxConnectionsToServer are not updating with the values provided in variables tab.

I tried the same release steps in different VSTS account, there it is updating all the three values correclty. But only in client VSTS account not updating all the three values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the result is that the [XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution#xmlvarsubs) of IIS Web App Deploy task just match the ‘key’ or ‘name’ entries in the **appSettings**, **applicationSettings**, **connectionStrings** and **configSections** (`<section …/>`) elements of the config file and parameters.xml.

So, the **IndexDirectory** value can be updated but others can’t. I recommend that you can define them in these sections (appSettings, connectionsStrings).

Comment: But I tried the same release steps in different VSTS account, there it is updating the all values. this is link for same question posted in developer  community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/193232/xml-varaiable-substitution-option-is-not-working-p.html

Comment: @pradeep Can you share that release (worked) log on the OneDrive (Add system.debug variable and set to true, then start release and share this log)?

Comment: This is the one drive link for logs after setting the system.debug is true under Variables tab. https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CwQPlWR5TWcBQdIwh

Comment: @pradeep Based on the log, it just updated IndexDirectory, is it the log of the release can update all values?

Comment: Yes starian that is the log of the release for updating all values.

Comment: Are the content of config files the same? Try to change the config file and do release, then check the deployed file in server whether it includes the changes.